# NSURLSession malloc_error

Tags: ios, ios8, malloc, nsurlsession

I am getting an intermittent malloc error with NSURLSession for uploads

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
  NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
  NSDictionary *httpResponse = [response allHeaderFields];
```

It fails on the all headerFields with

malloc: *** error for object 0x16acc000: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

only info I could find is but there is no solution
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2334

Comment: I have been told that this has been fixed in 8.2 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this looks like a iOS 8.1 bug :( I used to get this error in the past, working with a non-ARC project, when I used `release` twice accidentally on an attribute, so it's probably the application complaining that you're trying to free a section of the heap that has no allocated memory. Since not only you're using ARC and not freeing memory directly, but also you're getting this error randomly, it's likely that there's something wrong under the hood. Looking into the github you provided, it apparently only happens on iOS 8.1 but, could you confirm that?

Sorry for the crappy answer, I'll let you know if I happen to find something more about this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I suspected it may just be their bug.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in 8.2